# IntelXDK Uncaught ReferenceError: LocalFileSystem is not defined

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, intel-xdk

I try to download a locally generated file to the device file system. I was using a function that only works for chrome so I wanted to replace it by a Cordova based function. I added in IntelXDK:

-The Cordova plugins File and FileTransfer.

-The Android permissions WRITE_EXTERNAL-STORAGE and READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.

-The download function:

```
function downloadCordova2(filename, text){
        //NEXT SAVE IT TO THE DEVICE'S LOCAL FILE SYSTEM
        console.log("file system...");
        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem) {

            alert("in 1");
           console.log(fileSystem.name);
           console.log(fileSystem.root.name);
           console.log(fileSystem.root.fullPath);

           fileSystem.root.getFile("test.txt", {create: true}, function(entry) {
              var fileEntry = entry;
              console.log(entry);
             alert("in 2");
              entry.createWriter(function(writer) {
                 writer.onwrite = function(evt) {
                 console.log("write success");
              };

              console.log("writing to file");
                 writer.write( pdfOutput );
              }, function(error) {
                 console.log(error);
              });

           }, function(error){
              console.log(error);
           });
        },
        function(event){
         console.log( evt.target.error.code );
            alert(evt.target.error.message);
        });

    }
```

I get the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: LocalFileSystem is not defined" in the emulator, in chrome after building for chrome, in the emulator using a real Android device and, when I install the Android apk, I cannot see it but it doesn't work either.

Am I missing anything to include?
There are similar posts about this issue but the problems where missing plugins, permissions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After importing an HTML5 project to IntelXDK, you must add the script tag of the IntelXDK javascript source in the index.html file:

```
<script src="intelxdk.js"></script>
```

The file does not exist in the project source but, when building the project, IntelXDK will automatically copy it into the root of the sources, next to index.html